# Intersections of generating sets of subalgebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated, finitely presented, Noetherian, unital algebra over the complex numbers, which has no zero divisors. We do not assume that $A$ is commutative however.

Moreover, let $B$ and $C$ two finitely generated unital sub-algebras of $A$. For what types of generating sets $S_B$ and $S_C$, of $B$ and $C$ respectively, will a generating set of $B \cap C$ be given by $S_B \cap S_C$?

Comment: I presume you mean $B\cap C$ and not $A\cap B$? I’m afraid I can’t imagine what reasonable answer there could be that isn’t just a trivial restatement of the condition in the question.

Comment: Yes, it's $B \cap C$.

Comment: Are there extra conditions on $A$, or $B$, or $C$ one could require to make the question tractable?

Comment: Well, if $S_B$ and $S_C$ work, and there is some $s\in S_B$ that is not in $C$ (as there must be unless $B\subseteq C$), then you can add $s$ to every element of $S_B\cap C$ to get a new $S_B’$ so that $S_B’$ and $S_C$ don’t work. I’m just not sure what kind of condition you’d like that would allow $S_B$ and $S_C$, but not $S_B’$ and $S_C$.